# SQL GROUP BY distinct rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postges database with one very long table and 3 columns like so:

```
s_id | c_id | a_id
 1   |  1   |  2
 1   |  1   |  3
 1   |  3   |  15
 2   |  1   |  2
 2   |  2   |  23
 3   |  1   |  2
 3   |  3   |  16
```

I have a query that finds all s_ids that have c_id 1 and 3, returns them and their counts:

```
SELECT s_id, COUNT(s_id) as matching_clusters 
FROM test 
WHERE c_id IN (1,3) 
GROUP BY s_id HAVING COUNT(c_id) >= 2 
ORDER BY matching_clusters DESC
```

What I get back is the following:

```
s_id | matching_clusters
 1   |         3
 3   |         2
```

But, I only want to count recurring c_id once, such that results here should be

```
s_id | matching_clusters
 1   |         2
 3   |         2
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? I thought I can stick `DISTINCT` into the COUNT command, but that didn't work. I can probably join the result on table itself with distinct c_id but I don't want to re-run the query because running a query on this table is very expensive computation wise.

Comment: You mean HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c_id) didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then this will work:

```
SELECT s_id, 2 as matching_clusters 
FROM test 
WHERE c_id IN (1,3) 
GROUP BY s_id
HAVING COUNT(c_id) >= 2 
ORDER BY matching_clusters DESC;
```

This may be what you want:

```
SELECT s_id, COUNT(DISTINCT c_id) as matching_clusters 
FROM test 
WHERE c_id IN (1,3) 
GROUP BY s_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c_id) = 2 
ORDER BY matching_clusters DESC;
```

Note the use of `distinct` in the `having` clause.

Comment: is it necessary to use distinct in having clause also.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai, yes to avoid 1,1 to be valid (without any 3).

Comment: But i think without that only use distinct with count in select field works well.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . No, you need the distinct in both places.  They are separate expressions, not related to each other.

Comment: K nice, I previously used Distinct in HAVING clause, but you get 0 rows. I didn't realise I should COUNT DISTINCT as well. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
SELECT s_id, COUNT(DISTINCT s_id) as matching_clusters 
FROM test 
WHERE c_id IN (1,3) 
GROUP BY s_id HAVING COUNT(c_id) >= 2 
ORDER BY matching_clusters DESC
```

Comment: matching_clusters will always be 1 here, since group by s_id.

Comment: E.g. for each group of s_id = 1, the COUNT(DISTINCT s_id) will return 1.

Comment: What about where cond.??

Comment: Will still count 1,1 as 2 even though it's the same value. Create a table, insert data and try and see!